# Block a package from being uninstalled in APT

Tags: apt

In short, I want to be able to set package `abc` so that:

1. `apt-get remove abc` should fail.
2. `apt-get purge abc` should fail.
3. `apt-get upgrade abc` should work.

If the package dependencies change so that `abc` should be uninstalled during an `dist-upgrade` I am happy to being forced to do something and then `dist-upgrade` again.

Comment: I created an essential metapackage that depends on `abc`, but it was removed anyway... I think you have to recompile the `abc` setting `Essential: yes` and `Priority: required` in `debian/control`

Comment: @TeresaeJunior Strange, an essential package `def` depending on `abc` should have worked. Was `def` removed? Does it help if you make `def` `Priority: required`?

Comment: @Gilles Exactly, I set both `Essential: yes` and `Priority: required` and it was removed with no warnings. I created this small script to make the package, if you want to have a look: http://paste.org/44184

Comment: I see that `Essential: yes` was ignored, so `equivs` is not sufficient for that... Maybe if the package is created with `debuild`, I'll try.

Answer (score 5):

Not really anything to 'pin' a package down to be able to prevent removal, but allow upgrading.

You can hammer a spike into a package, can't be deleted, purged, upgraded, licked, anything...

But it's a wee bit more complicated than most things.

For example, we wish to pin firefox down:  (you'd use the proper full name of the package, of course)

```
echo firefox hold | dpkg --set-selections
```

which would then make '*firefox*' immortal.  **BUT**, it cannot be upgraded in this state either.

To remove the hold status is a bit easier, but it's kind of a sweeping gesture:

```
dpkg --clear-selections
```

removes the HOLD status from EVERYTHING!   So if you wanted to hold a few packages, you'd best keep a list to reapply later

It's actually quite pleasant and easy to perform using **aptitude** or **synaptics**, as they have menu options to hold/unhold a package, taking care of all the bookkeeping behind the scenes for you.  I'd recommend using one of those (or any of a myriad other package managers you might encounter)

With Aptitude, command line usage is possible too:

```
aptitude hold <package>
aptitude unhold <package>
```

Remember though, you'll need to '*unhold*' something if want it to upgrade.  Although if you use the GUI side of Aptitude, it should tell you if something that's held is upgradable

Comment: `apt-get` will happily uninstall a held package.